# Как указать что символ "|" это символ, а не знак ИЛИ?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Ищу в тексте символ "|" и заменяю его на "/n"

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("|","\n");
```

а потом обратно

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("\n|\r\n","|");
```

Только в первом случае Студия воспринимает черту как знак ИЛИ, а мне надо как символ (который обозначает "перевод каретки").

Как поправить это?

Comment: Экранируйте его.

Comment: Или используйте `replace` вместо `replaceAll`.

Comment: экранировать не получается.

Comment: а подойдет replace если надо весь текст, а не одно место?

Comment: _"черту как знак ИЛИ, а мне надо как символ (который обозначает "перевод каретки")"_ - а чего бы вдруг `|` считать как перевод каретки (`\r`)?

Comment: Пойдёт. Отличие одного от другого лишь, что `replaceAll` принимает регулярку, а  `replace` конкретную строку.

Comment: Regent, дело в том, что текст, который надо анализировать составлен не мной, и в нем использован символ "|", как символ перевода строки. Приходится "извращаться", чтобы потом использовать этот текст в другом месте.

Comment: Экранировал неправильно (одной чертой), а надо двумя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно заэкранировать символ `"|"` в регулярном выражении:

```
System.out.println("a|b|c|d|e|f".replaceAll("\\|", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае можно заменить `replaceAll` на `replace`.

Несмотря на не очевидные названия, оба метода заменят **все** вхождения, найденные в строке. Отличие лишь в том, что `replaceAll` принимает в качестве первого параметра регулярное выражение, а `replace` - просто последовательность символов. То есть во втором случае экранировать символ `|` не потребуется.